# C# Conditional statement on List

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, list

```
Public class AbcViewModel
{
    public string native{get; set;}
    public string other{get; set;}
    public List<AbcViewModel> abcList{get; set;}
}
```

Now that my View is strongly typed to this ViewModel, I need to check some condition before displaying fields.

From my Controller Action I am passing the list

```
public ActionResult actionName() 
{
    AbcViewModel viewModel=new AbcViewModel();
    viewModel=model.getAbcList();
    return View(viewModel);
}
```

**Condition:** If supposed my list contains `n` counts. Then if any "native element" of any index hold some value then display other fields and hide vice versa.

i.e.
Something like this

```
@if (Model.languageList.Any(x => x.nativeLanguage.IsNotEmpty() == false)
{ 
    @LabelFor(x=>x.other) 
}
else
{
    @LabelFor(x=>x.native)
}
```

This is not the correct syntax I think (IsNotEmpty is not a valid method).

Tell me the correct way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this

```
@if (Model.languageList.Any(x=> !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.nativeLanguage))==false){ @LabelFor(x=>x.other) }
    else{@LabelFor(x=>x.native)}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [String.IsNullOrEmpty Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorempty.aspx) to check whether the specified string is null or an Empty string.

try this:

```
@if (!Model.languageList.Any(x=> string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.nativeLanguage))
{ 
  @LabelFor(x=>x.other) 
 }
 else 
 {
   @LabelFor(x=>x.native)
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@if (Model.languageList.Any(x => string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.nativeLanguage))
{ 
    @LabelFor(x => x.other) 
}
else
{
    @LabelFor(x => x.native)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If is your list full of strings, then you should be able to call a method like this

```
String.IsNullOrEmpty(****)
```

If you have other datatypes as well, you can still write yourself a method to do the same job.